# error: bad operand types for binary operator '!=' if(Current_value != "."){ ^ first type: char second type: String

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {
        HashSet<String> seen= new HashSet();
        for(int i =0;i<9;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                char Current_value = board[i][j];
                if(Current_value != "."){
                    if(!seen.add(Current_value +"found in row"+i) || !seen.add(Current_value+"found in column"+j) || !seen.add(Current_value +"found in sub box"+i/3+ j/3))
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
        
        
    }
}
```

why this error is shown
Line 7: error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
if(Current_value != "."){
^
first type:  char
second type: String

Comment: "." is a String, '.' is the char version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is difference in "." and '.'. The former is a string and the latter one is a character. The compile time error you are sharing is because the relationship operator can compare values of identicial data types. To remove this error, change it to the following.

```
class Solution {
public boolean isValidSudoku(char[][] board) {
    HashSet<String> seen= new HashSet();
    for(int i =0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            char Current_value = board[i][j];
            if(Current_value != '.'){
                if(!seen.add(Current_value +"found in row"+i) || !seen.add(Current_value+"found in column"+j) || !seen.add(Current_value +"found in sub box"+i/3+ j/3));
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
    
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing String with char value.

```
char Current_value = board[i][j];
if(Current_value != '.'){
   if(!seen.add(Current_value +"found in row"+i) || !seen.add(Current_value+"found in column"+j) 
        || !seen.add(Current_value +"found in sub box"+i/3+ j/3));
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your if condition with this. As "." is a string

```
if(Current_value != '.'){
```